# Access box.com files by share link

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, box

I want to be able to serve up box.com documents to users on my password protected web site. I want to  to develop a little php program that will accept a box.com share link, and using the box.com api and a  OAUTH 2.0 token, retrieve the file from box.com, and then send it to my users.

Is this the best way to do this? There really isn't the need for an OAuth flow, as I am accessing my own files on box.com, I just want to make sure that my users are logged in.

I also don't want to simply share my box.com files to the whole internet.

My question: Is there a way to access a document on box.com via the api using the box share link. What I mean is that the share link looks like: https:/...domain.box.com/xxxxxxxxxx

Can I someone use the xxxxxxxxx as an ID to get/files/fileid/content api call?

Is there a way to search for a document by its share link?

I want to use the share link, because non-technical people will be generating contact, and I'm concerned that they will have trouble getting the FILEID of the box.com files.

Answer (score 0):

The Box documentation answers your question:

Create a shared link for a file:
https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file

Anyway, I'm working on a Box Php Sdk, I hope it helps you: https://github.com/adammbalogh/box-php-sdk

Comment: I don't want to create a shared link - because the document would have to have its permissions set to be readable by everyone. I want to restrict the accessible to people who are logged into another system that I control. So the box doc retrieval web service that I will build will access the files and serve them up. I wanted to use the shared link because that's more intuitive than the fileid.